# How to return a value from an async method in a static helper class the right way?

Tags: java, android

I have a basic class which has a static method with a following call of another helper method.

```
MsBandHelper.connectToSelectedBand(bandClient);
```

The helper method:

```
public static void connectToSelectedBand(BandClient bandClient) {
        try {
            MsBandConnectHelperAssync asyncTask = new MsBandConnectHelperAssync(new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(Boolean output) {
                    try {
                        Logger.d("HELPER METHOD RETURNED " + output);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.e(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            asyncTask.execute(bandClient);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I am able to get result in processFinish of this method, but I don't know how I should pass the returned value back to the calling because it is an async method.

If I tried to implement interface which i'm using in MsBandConnectHelperAssync class no interface event was triggered.

Should i create a new interface on can i broadcast result into all bound classes?

How can i do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Include the callback in the static method parameter and pass it to asynctask - `public static void connectToSelectedBand(BandClient bandClient, AsyncResponse response)` . And inside method `try {
            MsBandConnectHelperAssync asyncTask = new MsBandConnectHelperAssync(response);
            asyncTask.execute(bandClient);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }`

Comment: Please don't prefix question titles with a tag. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles